# How to set up links to open up images, videos and audio

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, anchor

I have three table rows which contains a list of Images, Videos and Audio in their respective rows:

```
    echo '<td width="11%" class="imagetd">'. ( ( empty ($arrImageFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : '<ul class="qandaul"><li>'.htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrImageFile[$key] ) ? implode(",", $arrImageFile[$key]) : $arrImageFile[$key] ) ). '</li></ul></td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td width="11%" class="videotd">'. ( ( empty ($arrVideoFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : '<ul class="qandaul"><li>'.htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrVideoFile[$key] ) ? implode(",", $arrVideoFile[$key]) : $arrVideoFile[$key] ) ). '</li></ul></td>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<td width="11%" class="audiotd">'. ( ( empty ($arrAudioFile[$key]) ) ? "&nbsp;" : '<ul class="qandaul"><li>'.htmlspecialchars( is_array( $arrAudioFile[$key] ) ? implode(",", $arrAudioFile[$key]) : $arrAudioFile[$key] ) ). '</li></ul></td>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Now at the moment it just lists the image, video and audio file names in a bullet point list. But what I want to do is that I want to set each file as a hyperlink so that if th user clicks on either of the links, it will display the image, video or audio in a seperate page (a seperate window will opn up), either as a larger or displaying a player to play the video or audio.

My question is how can this be done, what are the following steps I need to do?

Thanks

UPDATE:

The list is an array which contains data coming from the database. Below is the code for the video array and database. The audio and image has a similar set up

```
    $vidquery = "SELECT s.SessionId, q.QuestionId, v.VideoId, VideoFile
                FROM Session s
                INNER JOIN Question q ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId
                INNER JOIN Video_Question vq ON q.QuestionId = vq.QuestionId
                INNER JOIN Video v ON vq.VideoId = v.VideoId
                WHERE s.SessionId = ?";

    global $mysqli;
    $vidqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($vidquery);
    // You only need to call bind_param once
    $vidqrystmt->bind_param("i",$_POST["session"]);
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $vidqrystmt->execute(); 
    $vidqrystmt->bind_result($vidSessionId,$vidQuestionId,$vidVideoId,$vidVideoFile);

        $arrVideoFile = array();

    while ($vidqrystmt->fetch()) {
    $arrVideoFile[] = basename($vidVideoFile);
  }

    $vidqrystmt->close();
```

Comment: you should  use the a tag

Comment: Where is the list coming from. Show us how you are populating it. this is where you will need to read the files and create the proper links

Comment: @ROYFinley I Included an update showing where list comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep separate divs for image,audio,video files.
in image div ex:

```
<img alt="Loading" id="tempImg" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" src="">
```

like audio div

```
<object id='tempAud1' name="emQTPlayer" height="45px" width="120px"
                    style="behavior: url(#BinaryBehaviorID)"
                    codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab"
                    classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B">
                    <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
                    <param name="src"
                        value="" />
                    <param name="controller" value="true" />
                    <param name="type" value="video/quicktime" />
                    <param name="align" value="bottom" />
                    <param name="border" value="0" />
                    <%--                        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">--%>
                    <param name="showcontrols" value="true">
                    <embed id='tempAud2' name="emQTPlayer" type="video/quicktime"
                        autoplay="false" height="45px" width="120px" align="top"
                        border="0" controller="true" postdomevents="true"
                        pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
                        showcontrols="true"
                        src='' />
                </object>
```

and for video div use

```
<object id='tempVid1' name="emQTPlayer" height="240px"
                    width="320px" style="behavior: url(#BinaryBehaviorID)"
                    codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab"
                    classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B">
                    <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
                    <param name="src"
                        value="" />
                    <param name="controller" value="true" />
                    <param name="type" value="video/quicktime" />
                    <param name="align" value="bottom" />
                    <param name="border" value="0" />
                    <param name="scale" value="tofit" />
                    <%--                                    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">--%>
                    <param name="showcontrols" value="true">
                    <embed id='tempVid2' name="emQTPlayer" type="video/quicktime"
                        autoplay="false" height="auto" width="auto" align="top"
                        border="0" controller="true" postdomevents="true"
                        pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
                        showcontrols="true" scale="tofit"
                        src='' />
                </object>
```

... In the onclick event of on the file names pass the src value to a javascript function and set it to the respetive src....

Comment: thanks for answer. SO I am assuming what you want me to do is put this page on a seperate php script, and then going back to my current script make my image, video and audion filenames into hyperlinks and then set up a javascript function to have an onclick event to pass the src to..., that will be the issue, do I pass the source to a seperate page or something like that?

Comment: actually i don't know much about php. But i done same thing for my gallery module in my JAVA code.. But there i"ll be streaming the file from server with respective content types and will get that from client page..